# Create SSH Connection Independent Of Calling Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I am trying to create a bash script that serves as a wrapper for numerous ssh connection options. Basically the user will run the script and the appropriate ssh command will then be created and executed based on their selections. I am trying to find a way to have the script exit and the ssh connection created, rather than having the script continue to run while the user is working on the remote server. Does anyone know if this is possible or how I could achieve this? Thanks!

**Edit**
Sorry, I should have posted my code:

```
display_main_menu(){
while true
do
        clear
        echo ""
        echo " Select A Server:"
        echo " -------------------------------"
        echo "  1) Server 1"
        echo "  2) Server 2"
        echo "  3) Server 3"
        echo "  4) Quit"

    local selection
        read -p " Enter choice [1 - 4] " selection
        case $selection in
                1)
                        # Open SSH Connection to Server 1
                        break
                        ;;
                2)
            # Open SSH Connection to Server 2
                        break
                        ;;
                3)
                        # Open SSH Connection to Server 3
                        break
                        ;;
                4)
                        exit 0
            break
                        ;;
                        ;;
                *)
                        echo -e "Invalid Selection..." && sleep 2
                        ;;
        esac
done
}
```

Comment: Please post your code it will be useful to recognize your question

Comment: @willie Sorry, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
exec ssh <pararameters>
```

The exec builtin command:

**Synopsis**

exec [-a NAME] [-cl] [COMMAND] [ARG...] [REDIRECTION...]

**Description**

The exec builtin command is used to

- replace the shell with a given program (executing it, not as new
  process)
- set redirections for the program to execute or for the
  current shell

If only redirections are given, the redirections affect the current shell without executing any program.